# For my surprise this code compiles and executes correctly. What's happening here?

Tags: c++, templates

I obtained the example below from [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm#1) under the subtitle "The Solution".

For me the evaluation of the second argument in the call `std::accumulate(a, a + 10, 0);` in `main()` would have to precede the `std::accumulate()` function call. That is, the `operator+(N::C, int)` in namespace `N` would have to be called before the function `std::accumulate()`. But not only this operator is **not** defined, but the code compiles and executes normally. What's happening here?

```
namespace N
{
    class C {};
    int operator+(int i, N::C) { return i+1; }
}

#include <numeric>
int main()
{
    N::C a[10];
    std::accumulate(a, a + 10, 0);
}
```

Instead this template function is invoked

```
template<class _InIt,
    class _Ty> inline
    _Ty accumulate(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Ty _Val)
    {   // return sum of _Val and all in [_First, _Last)
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    return (_Accumulate(_Unchecked(_First), _Unchecked(_Last), _Val));
    }
```

where `_InIt = N::C` and `_Ty = int`. I don't understand much about templates, but how can the compiler deduce that `a + 10` is also an `N::C`?

Comment: ... it *has* to be - you told it so when you made an array of `N::C` objects.  Strictly speaking `a + 10` is a pointer to an `N::C`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a + 10` doesn't call any operator of your class.  It just adds `10` to `a`, which, being an array, decays into a pointer to its first element in this context.  Your code is equivalent to:

```
std::accumulate(&a[0], &a[10], 0);
```

No `+` to operate on your object at all.

Comment: So what you're saying is that in the template function, `_Init = N::C*` and not `N::C`.

Comment: I guess so?  I'm not really a C++ expert.